# Visual Studio 2012 Build Error Message - The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task was not found. Check the following:

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm encountering the following error message when I build/rebuild my MVC .NET 4.0 solution in Visual Studio 2012:

The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory.

Don't know how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the three following steps could help:

- Cleaning the solution
- restarting VS
- restarting Windows